# Change checked mark color of checkbox in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I need to change check mark color of the checkbox in the flutter and there is no parameter is given to change color in Checkbox.

```
Checkbox(
   value: isCheck,
   activeColor: Colors.grey,
   onChanged: (bool value) {
   setState(() { isCheck = value;});
       })
```

dart class code

```
  const Checkbox({
    Key key,
    @required this.value,
    this.tristate = false,
    @required this.onChanged,
    this.activeColor,
    this.materialTapTargetSize,
  }) : assert(tristate != null),
       assert(tristate || value != null),
       super(key: key);
```

Comment: What you are looking is present on `master` & `dev` branch - `checkColor`

Comment: run command `flutter channel dev` to switch to dev channel of flutter in terminal

Comment: @anmol.majhail  how can i return `_CheckboxRenderObjectWidget ` box object so that i can implement their field.

Comment: @pskink no I have n't seen.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Right now I am Using -

> Flutter (Channel dev, v1.2.2,)

Option to change the Checkmark Color is not present on stable channel.

```
Checkbox(
          value: isCheck,
          checkColor: Colors.yellowAccent,  // color of tick Mark
          activeColor: Colors.grey,
          onChanged: (bool value) {
            setState(() {
              isCheck = value;
            });
          }),
```

Comment: `checkColor` parameter is not defined.

Comment: that what i mentioned in answer - change to channel dev from stable. run command `flutter channel dev` to switch to dev channel of flutter in terminal.

Comment: will it not affect the live project if I sifted to stable to dev. flutter

Comment: if it can affect the project so I can't do that, any other option

Comment: It won't effect as such, but you can always shift back - with `flutter channel stable`. So you can try - dev channel if things didn't go as expected - revert to stable channel. make sure you run `flutter clean` to delete the build.

Comment: okay, I got your point and I would like to stay on a stable version so that I can complete my project after that I will change the channel. one more question if I back to stable version then all the changes of dev. version will go.

Comment: build release apk with dev - that apk will work with dev features even after reverting to stable. after reverting to stable feature given by dev will go away in new build - yes.

Answer (score 67):

To change color of a checkbox:

When inactive (border color):

```
Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      child: Checkbox(...),
    )
```

When checked (icon color):

```
Checkbox(
        checkColor: Colors.red,
        ...
      )
```

When active (checked):

```
Checkbox(
        activeColor: Colors.amberAccent,
        ...
      )
```

Full Code Sample:

```
Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      child: Checkbox(
        checkColor: Colors.red,
        activeColor: Colors.amberAccent,
        value: _terms,
        onChanged: (bool value) {
          setState(() {
            _terms = value;
          });
        },
      ),
    )
```

Comment: I am confused - should there not a setting for the checkbox in the theme. My checkbox has always a different color than the buttons. I don't want to set it on each checkbox rather once global in the theme

Comment: Thumbs up for solution and more options(in my case I was searching for unselectedWidgetColor)

Comment: The `Theme.of` part doesn't change the checkbox border color (in Flutter 3.17, at least). You have to use `side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white)` inside the `Checkbox`.

Answer (score 24):

If you don't want to set it in each checkbox than use this:

```
new ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
  unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.orange.shade800,
  toggleableActiveColor: Colors.orange.shade800,
```

Answer (score 17):

You can change checkbox color globally in the app using theme:

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    checkboxTheme: CheckboxThemeData(
      checkColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white),
      fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.orange),
    )
  )
);
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to modify only one `CheckBox` with its colors, you won't like to use `Theme`. All the other solutions won't show you how to also modify the color of the inactive `CheckBox`. The inactive Checkbox is just a `BorderSide`, so:

```dart
Checkbox(
  checkColor: Colors.white,
  activeColor: Colors.green,
  side:
      BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.green),
  value: _accepted,
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      _accepted = value;
    });
  },
),
```

This will give you a green `CheckBox` with a white check arrow:

[image: A green checkbox with a white arrow turning on and off]

Answer (score 4):

**My solution for customizing Checkboxes**

Custom:

- Size
- Border-radius
- Background
- No border

```
class AppCheckbox extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool value;
  final bool disabled;
  final double size;
  final ValueChanged<bool> onChanged;

  const AppCheckbox({
    Key key,
    this.size = 24,
    this.value = false,
    this.disabled = false,
    this.onChanged,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final backColor = disabled ? AppColors.white8 : AppColors.white24;
    final checkColor = disabled ? AppColors.white56 : Colors.white;

    return Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        disabledColor: Colors.transparent,
        unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      child: SizedBox(
        width: size,
        height: size,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: backColor,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
          ),
          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
          child: Transform.scale(
            scale: size / Checkbox.width,
            child: Checkbox(
              hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
              focusColor: Colors.transparent,
              activeColor: Colors.transparent,
              checkColor: checkColor,
              value: value,
              onChanged: disabled
                  ? null
                  : (value) {
                      onChanged(value);
                    },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can change it with the bool variable which is `isCheck` in your case like this :

```
Checkbox(
   value: isCheck,
   activeColor: isCheck ? Colors.green: Colors.grey ,
   onChanged: (bool value) {
   setState(() { isCheck = value;});
       })
```

Comment: I'm able to change active color but want to change Checked mark color and thanks for answering.