# Flutter Checkbox background

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, checkbox, widget

The main problem of Checkbox widget is that it has transparent background, and the way it takes the space is around checkbox itself, so even if you managed to wrap it with container it will change the space around checkbox also.

I'm looking for a best non-package solution if there is any, because making it like 'two pictures changing' with no animation feels weird.

To be more clear I'm adding code with wrapping it with Container, I want green color ***only inside*** checkbox

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    color: Colors.green,
    child: Checkbox(
      value: false,
      fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white),
      onChanged: (value) {},
    ),
  );
}
```

I want make it inside color white or dark green for example.

[image: example with container]

Another example from Figma

[image: unckeched color]

Comment: So you want to have a different background for your checkbox?

Comment: Does this answer help you where someone creates a custom widget for it? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65105861/2641242

Comment: @jraufeisen not really(

Answer (score 0):

you have to way to change `checkColor`

first used checkColor and fillColor property

```
Checkbox(
          value: isCheck,
          checkColor: Colors.green, // color of tick Mark
          fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red),
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              isCheck = value!;
            });
          },
        ),
```

[image]

Second used checkColor and fillColor property

```
Checkbox(
          value: isCheck,
          checkColor: Colors.green, // color of tick Mark
          activeColor: Colors.red,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              isCheck = value!;
            });
          },
        ),
```

[image]

**the difference between `fill Color` and `active color` than `fill Color` is change unselect border color**

Comment: I'm really sorry for making question not clear for you. But the question is about ***unselected*** color of checkbox background, you can see it on screen if put some brightness up.